# count of all records stored Extended Event

Tags: sql-server, count, extended-events

I want to get count of all records stored in Extended Event but that file is a huge and running a query on it takes several minutes and does not meet my need.
I wanted to know is there any place in the sql server to get this data there? I mean something like  sys.traces or event_count

I write  query but this is not work

```
SELECT COUNT(timestamp_utc) 
FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file(N'D:\Extended Event\ErrorReport\ex_*.xel', NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can export it to csv file as, it is explained [in this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/advanced-viewing-of-target-data-from-extended-events-in-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Then, you can import the csv file into a sql server using [Bulk insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Bulk insert execution is very fast unless you don't use indexes in the target Table, [see here](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-bulk-insert-concurrency-and-performance-considerations/)

Then you can query the SQL SERVER Table to which you imported the Data.

[image]